# How do I create one set of HTML and load different information into multiple popups using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a div that acts as an informational box/popup with a fair bit of html code, css styles and multiple UL's that data is loaded into.

I want to use this single box html code to open multiple copies of this box at the same time displaying different data.

The box is currently using ID's as selectors and it's inside a popup. It's positioned absolutely and will travel with the draggable popup.

The other boxes will work the same way displaying similar user information but will load information based on other variables.

What I want to be able to do is use one set of html code but load information into the appropriate info box and not affect any of the other boxes which already have information loaded into them.

I can easily do this by coping the code and giving everything different id's and bloating the jQuery code to push info into these "copies" of the html code. I'd rather not do that.

Is there a standard method for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at KnockoutJS http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is templating and data-loading?

Comment: KnockoutJS has a templating engine: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html, but if the data loaded into each popup cannot be standardised easily, you may just want to copy and paste the HTML markup for multiple popups and then change bindings inside each one. Knockout won't specifically do the loading, but if you use jQuery to load the data (not specified what this is, Ajax maybe?) you just need to store it in observables, observableArrays or computed observables to be able to bind it to HTML elements contained within your popup(s).